# как использовать переменную место названия массива?

Tags: javascript

я получаю данные из массива этим способом
`let info = data.numb1[0].name`
как вместо `numb1` вставить переменную, в которой будет записано другое название?

Comment: `data[peremennaja][0].name`

Comment: @Igor, так пытался, но выдает ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Значит переменная `peremennaja` содержит неправильное значение. Мы можем угадать все что угодно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = {
  numb1: [{name: 'Test1'}],
  numb2: [{name: 'Test2'}]
};

let peremennaja = 'numb2';
let info = data[peremennaja][0].name;
console.log(info);
console.log(data['numb1'][0].name);
```